# How can I avoid reflections when using polymorphism in PHP

Tags: php, oop, reflection, polymorphism

I have a situation where I have a "Task" class that can "progress"

However each Task has different required param to know how to progress, and therefore the "progress" should receive different parameters.

What I did was making sure each "Task" implements an "ITask" interface which forces the implementaion of "progress" method.
The parameter for the "prgoress" method is "ITaskProgress" interface, which will allow me to put the right task progress for each task.

The problem is I need to reflect the taskProgress inside the Task when I use it to progress, to know which members/method exists inside the "taskProgress" so I can use it to progress.

I don't feel this is the right way, how would you put the pieces together the right way?

**Assume that because Task and Task Progress have to be saved in different places they cannot live under the same class.**

```
interface ITaskProgress {};
interface ITask
{
    function progress(ITaskProgress $taskProgress);
}
class DoThisTaskPrgoress implements ITaskProgress
{
    public $needThisToProgress;
}

class DoThatTaskProgress implements ITaskProgress
{
    public $needThatToProgress;
    public $alsoNeeded;
}

class DoThisTask implements ITask
{

    function progress(ITaskProgress $taskProgress)
    {
        if ($taskProgress instanceof DoThisTaskPrgoress)
        {
            $taskProgress->needThisToProgress++;
        }
    }
}

class DoThatTask implements ITask
{
    function progress(ITaskProgress $taskProgress)
    {
        if ($taskProgress instanceof DoThatTaskProgress)
        {
            if ($taskProgress->needThatToProgress > $taskProgress->alsoNeeded)
            {
                $taskProgress->needThatToProgress = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For now it's not clear what you are asking. You do not show any reflection. And it's not clear why you would need to.

Comment: "instanceof" is a reflection

Comment: I disagree, but you can tell it opinion based.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone it's actually not an opinion, but definition of reflection

Comment: Show me the definition. For me reflection begins, when *reflecting* the structure of any runtime entity, i.e. building a parallel type information structure loading the type definition which is not usually available at runtime. Just picking the type information immediately from a script object already carrying it has nothing to do with reflection for me.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, as you can see in my code example, while you're calling the "progress" method you're reflecting the "taskProgress" parameter to know which type it is. This is exactly what reflection is, asking what is your class. As in putting a mirror in front of the class and asking "who are you?"

Comment: Then you had to call `foreach` as "reflection" as well, since it needs to "reflect" property names of objects (and other structures) as well. That's more reflection than getting the already available type. Your definition turns almost everything in a script language into a reflection. I strongly distinguish between scripting and a compiling into native code. Those are total different concepts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187171/discussion-between-jacob-cohen-and-quasimodos-clone).

Comment: To the implementation logic... It does not seem to make sense to excessively use interfaces in that way here. This generic example does not point out really good any purpose of the classes, so it is hard to say how it could be done. One could implement one proper way, however, then you come back and say: "But in this way I cannot ..."

Comment: One problem in your code is having public properties. That's not always bad, however, very frequently you should consider to use private/protected properties in conjunction with getters and setters. The latter can be part of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit opinionated as an answer, but as far as you're interested in my opinion, I think you can trust your feelings and should lean stronger on them:

> I don't feel this is the right way, how would you put the pieces together the right way?

Also the question title makes it clear that you dislike to use reflections. So getting rid of reflections is probably a good way to put things into the right way.

So right now you need to analyse an object so that you can use it. This normally is pretty cumbersome with objects, your case is just another example of that.

But why is it so cumbersome? Well to benefit of objects they should be more abstract. However here in your case (please don't see it as an insult, just as another example) you need to write very specialized code only to use the object ([*Tell Don't Ask*](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)).

This is sort of as if it turned inside-out. Instead of that the progress of a task is an implementation detail, the task itself needs to deal with different kind of progresses.

So how to resolve this? First of all don't do what you don't want to do (and only do what you must do, according to your question, that is if I understood you right all the things to deal with the obstacle of *"polymorphism"* [the way you name it]), so remove the `if`s:

```
class DoThisTask implements ITask
{

    function progress(DoThisTaskPrgoress $taskProgress)
    {
        $taskProgress->needThisToProgress++;
    }
}

class DoThatTask implements ITask
{
    function progress(DoThatTaskProgress $taskProgress)
    {
        if ($taskProgress->needThatToProgress > $taskProgress->alsoNeeded)
        {
            $taskProgress->needThatToProgress = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So now this feels better as the reflection (type checks) are moved out of the progress implementation.

The specific contract is now only between the caller of some task's progress method needing to take care to provide the correct concrete task progress parameter.

As PHP has no concept of "friends" in visibility, type-hinting the more specific task progress type (in comparison to the task progress interface) is crucial here so that it is clear which specific type the progress expects to work on ([*Don't Look for Things*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)).

And this brings us closer to [*inversion of control*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) which we can experience  often in object oriented programming. Now it is clear that telling a task to progress needs a specific task progress, an object representing state injected as method parameter.

If this is the foremost design you choose to solve your overall problem, it should also guide you in finding the parenting pattern for your object oriented design. E.g. it looks like you need (at least a very small) abstract factory so whatever is progressing is from a family of classes (progress *and* task) so a central factory can provide this family. And the factory can be injected (inversion of control) so that this family of classes can be "one" in your overall application.

Which task then needs which progress then can be resolved by the factory and the rest of your code should just work(tm).

Comment: Your solution just moves the problem to another place.
Now the one who holds the "ITask" needs to know that he has the right "TaskProgress" in his hand before he calls "progress".
Also "progress" is not longer an interface, and since PHP has no overloading, you will lose the ability to know that ITask has progress at all, since they hold different signatures.

Comment: Yes sure, it's moved into the factory which takes care of it at object construction time. Which is actually the reason why an ITask does not need to know it has the right TaskProgress, it just get it injected (inversion of control). And the interface on progress you can keep, it's just pretty segragated and might even consist of no public method at all - but you can keep it to share meaning.